# how to calculate duration with cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i want to calculate duration for a given task/event. I am using cloud functions. I have four fields in flutter app;

1. Start date
2. Start time
3. End date
4. End time

how can i calculate the duration. Please help. i am using typescript for my cloud functions.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'


admin.initializeApp()

export const updateCharts = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{UserId}/count/{uid}')
.onWrite(async(change, _) => await updateStats(change))

async function updateStats (change: 
functions.Change<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>){
const chartRating = change.after.ref.parent

let title = (await chartRating.where('Title', '==', 'Game').get()).size;
//duration

const restaurantRef = chartRating.parent!

console.log('{restaurantRef.path} now has ${Title}')
await restaurantRef.update({
Title: Title,

})
```

Comment: console.time() -> console.timeEnd()

Answer (score 1):

```
// place this code where you want to measure from.
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
...

// place this code where you want to get the difference
var diff = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
```

Use the [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to get the time in total milliseconds since 1970-01-01.